# How do I link to libusb which has been built from source instead of the system library?

Tags: c++, makefile, libusb-1.0

I know my question is rather basic, and I'm a little embarrassed to have to ask. So I'm having some trouble using VRUI with my Oculus Rift, and Im having USB problems, so for a sanity check I downloaded the source for libusub-1.0.19-rc2 and am trying to link to the compiled version of this instead of the system library version. I'm using ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Thanks

EDIT:
So the relevant part of my program makefile (the whole thing is rather long) looks something like this:

```
########################################################################
# Makefile for Vrui toolkit and required basic libraries.
# Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Oliver Kreylos
#
# This file is part of the WhyTools Build Environment.
# 
# The WhyTools Build Environment is free software; you can redistribute
# it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
# as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the
# License, or (at your option) any later version.
# 
# The WhyTools Build Environment is distributed in the hope that it will
# be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty
# of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
# General Public License for more details.
# 
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with the WhyTools Build Environment; if not, write to the Free
# Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place, Suite 330, Boston, MA
# 02111-1307 USA
########################################################################

########################################################################
# The root directory where Vrui will be installed when running
# "make install". This must be a different directory than the one that
# contains this makefile, i.e., Vrui cannot be built in-tree. If the
# installation directory is changed from the default, the makefiles of
# Vrui applications typically need to be changed to use the same
# installation directory.
########################################################################

INSTALLDIR := $(HOME)/Vrui-3.1

########################################################################
# Please do not change the following lines
########################################################################

# Define the root of the toolkit source tree and the build system
# directory
VRUI_PACKAGEROOT := $(shell pwd)
VRUI_MAKEDIR := $(VRUI_PACKAGEROOT)/BuildRoot

# Include definitions for the system environment and provided software
# packages
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/SystemDefinitions
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.System

########################################################################
# Some settings that might need adjustment. In general, do not bother
# with these unless something goes wrong during the build process, or
# you have very specific requirements. Proceed with caution!
# The settings below are conservative; see the README file for what they
# mean, and how they depend on capabilities of the host system.
########################################################################

# The build system attempts to auto-detect the presence of system
# libraries that provide optional features. If autodetection fails and
# the build process generates error messages related to missing include
# files during compiling or missing libraries during linking, the use
# of these optional libraries can be disabled manually by uncommenting
# any of the following lines.

# SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBUSB1 = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBPNG = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBJPEG = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBTIFF = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_ALSA = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_SPEEX = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_OPENAL = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_V4L2 = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_DC1394 = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_THEORA = 0
# SYSTEM_HAVE_BLUETOOTH = 0

# The build system attempts to auto-detect optional features in system
# libraries. If autodetection fails and the build process generates
# error messages related to undeclared functions, the use of these
# optional features can be disabled manually by uncommenting any of the
# following lines:

# Presense of libusb_get_parent in libusb.h:
# LIBUSB1_HAS_TOPOLOGY_CALLS 0

########################################################################
# Please do not change the following line
########################################################################

# Include definitions for Vrui-provided software packages
include $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.Vrui

########################################################################
# More settings that might need adjustment. In general, do not bother
# with these unless something goes wrong during the build process, or
# you have very specific requirements. Proceed with caution!
# The settings below are conservative; see the README file for what they
# mean, and how they depend on capabilities of the host system.
########################################################################

# Set this to 1 if Vrui executables and shared libraries shall contain
# links to any shared libraries they link to. This will relieve a user
# from having to set up a dynamic library search path.
USE_RPATH = 1

# Set the following flag to 1 if the GL support library shall contain
# support for multithreaded rendering to several windows. This is
# required for shared-memory multi-pipe rendering systems such as SGI
# Onyx or Prism, but somewhat reduces performance when accessing per-
# window data elements or OpenGL extensions. If the compiler and run-
# time environment do not support a direct mechanism for thread-local
# storage (such as gcc's __thread extension), this uses the even slower
# POSIX thread-local storage mechanism. If setting this to 1 causes
# compilation errors, the SYSTEM_HAVE_TLS variable in
# BuildRoot/SystemDefinitions needs to be set to 0.
GLSUPPORT_USE_TLS = 0

# Set this to 1 if the VRWindow class shall be compiled with support for
# swap locks and swap groups (NVidia extension). This is only necessary
# in very rare cases; if you don't already know you need it, leave this
# setting at 0.
# If this is set to 1 and the NVidia extension is not there,
# VRWindow.cpp will generate compiler errors.
VRUI_VRWINDOW_USE_SWAPGROUPS = 0

# Set this to 1 if the operating system supports the input abstraction
# layer. If this is set to 1 and the input abstraction is not supported,
# Joystick.cpp will generate compiler errors.
VRDEVICES_USE_INPUT_ABSTRACTION = 0

# Set this to 1 if the Linux input.h header file has the required
# structure definitions (usually on newer Linux versions). If this is
# set wrongly, HIDDevice.cpp will generate compiler errors.
# This setting is ignored on MacOS X.
VRDEVICES_INPUT_H_HAS_STRUCTS = 1

# Set this to 1 if the Vrui VR device driver shall support Nintendo Wii
# controllers using the bluez user-level Bluetooth library. This
# requires that bluez is installed on the host computer, and that the
# path to the bluez header files / libraries is set properly in
# $(VRUI_MAKEDIR)/Packages.
# For now, the following code tries to automatically determine whether
# bluez is supported. This might or might not work.
VRDEVICES_USE_BLUETOOTH = $(SYSTEM_HAVE_BLUETOOTH)

########################################################################
# Please do not change anything below this line
########################################################################

# Specify version of created dynamic shared libraries
VRUI_VERSION = 3001002
MAJORLIBVERSION = 3
MINORLIBVERSION = 1
VRUI_NAME := Vrui-$(MAJORLIBVERSION).$(MINORLIBVERSION)

# Set additional debug options
ifdef DEBUG
  CFLAGS += -DDEBUG
endif

# Set destination directory for libraries and executables
LIBDESTDIR := $(VRUI_PACKAGEROOT)/$(MYLIBEXT)

# Override the include file and library search directories:
VRUI_INCLUDEDIR = $(VRUI_PACKAGEROOT)
VRUI_LIBDIR = $(VRUI_PACKAGEROOT)/$(MYLIBEXT)

# Directories for installation components
ifdef SYSTEMINSTALL
  HEADERINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/$(INCLUDEEXT)/$(VRUI_NAME)
  ifdef DEBUG
    LIBINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/$(LIBEXT)/$(VRUI_NAME)/debug
    EXECUTABLEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/$(BINEXT)/debug
  else
    LIBINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/$(LIBEXT)/$(VRUI_NAME)
    EXECUTABLEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/$(BINEXT)
  endif
  ETCINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/etc/$(VRUI_NAME)
  SHAREINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/share/$(VRUI_NAME)
  PKGCONFIGINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/$(LIBEXT)/pkgconfig
  DOCINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/usr/share/doc/$(VRUI_NAME)
  INSTALLROOT = /usr
else
  ifeq ($(findstring $(VRUI_NAME),$(INSTALLDIR)),$(VRUI_NAME))
    INSTALLSHIM = 
  else
    INSTALLSHIM = /$(VRUI_NAME)
  endif
  HEADERINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(INCLUDEEXT)
  ifdef DEBUG
    LIBINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(LIBEXT)/debug
    EXECUTABLEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(BINEXT)/debug
  else
    LIBINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(LIBEXT)
    EXECUTABLEINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(BINEXT)
  endif
  ETCINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/etc$(INSTALLSHIM)
  SHAREINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/share$(INSTALLSHIM)
  PKGCONFIGINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/$(LIBEXT)/pkgconfig
  DOCINSTALLDIR = $(INSTALLDIR)/share/doc$(INSTALLSHIM)
  INSTALLROOT = $(INSTALLDIR)
endif
PLUGININSTALLDIR = $(LIBINSTALLDIR)
ifdef DEBUG
  MAKEINSTALLDIR = $(SHAREINSTALLDIR)/make/debug
else
  MAKEINSTALLDIR = $(SHAREINSTALLDIR)/make
endif

########################################################################
# Specify additional compiler and linker flags
########################################################################

# Set flags to distinguish between static and shared libraries
ifdef STATIC_LINK
  LIBRARYNAME = $(LIBDESTDIR)/$(1).$(LDEXT).a
  OBJDIREXT = Static
else
  CFLAGS += $(CDSOFLAGS)
  LIBRARYNAME = $(LIBDESTDIR)/$(call FULLDSONAME,$(1))
endif

########################################################################
# List packages used by this project
# (Supported packages can be found in ./BuildRoot/Packages)
########################################################################

PACKAGES = 

########################################################################
# Specify all final targets
########################################################################

LIBRARIES = 
PLUGINS = 
EXECUTABLES = 

#
# The basic libraries:
#

LIBRARY_NAMES    = libMisc \
                   libThreads
ifneq ($(SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBUSB1),0)
  LIBRARY_NAMES += libUSB
endif
LIBRARY_NAMES   += libIO \
                   libPlugins \
                   libRealtime \
                   libComm \
                   libCluster \
                   libMath \
                   libGeometry \
                   libGLWrappers \
                   libGLSupport \
                   libGLXSupport \
                   libGLGeometry \
                   libImages \
                   libGLMotif \
                   libSound \
                   libVideo \
                   libALSupport \
                   libSceneGraph \
                   libVrui

LIBRARIES += $(LIBRARY_NAMES:%=$(call LIBRARYNAME,%))

#
# The Vrui VR tool plug-in hierarchy:
#

VRTOOLS_SOURCES = $(wildcard Vrui/Tools/*.cpp)

VRTOOLSDIREXT = VRTools
VRTOOLSDIR= $(LIBDESTDIR)/$(VRTOOLSDIREXT)
VRTOOLS = $(VRTOOLS_SOURCES:Vrui/Tools/%.cpp=$(VRTOOLSDIR)/lib%.$(PLUGINFILEEXT))
PLUGINS += $(VRTOOLS)

#
# The Vrui vislet plug-in hierarchy:
#

VRVISLETS_SOURCES = $(wildcard Vrui/Vislets/*.cpp)

VRVISLETSDIREXT = VRVislets
VRVISLETSDIR = $(LIBDESTDIR)/$(VRVISLETSDIREXT)
VRVISLETS = $(VRVISLETS_SOURCES:Vrui/Vislets/%.cpp=$(VRVISLETSDIR)/lib%.$(PLUGINFILEEXT))
PLUGINS += $(VRVISLETS)

#
# The VR device driver daemon:
#

EXECUTABLES += $(EXEDIR)/VRDeviceDaemon

#
# The VR device driver plug-ins:
#

# Don't build the following device modules unless explicitly asked later:
VRDEVICES_IGNORE_SOURCES = VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/Joystick.cpp \
                           VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/VRPNConnection.cpp \
                           VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/Wiimote.cpp \
                           VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/WiimoteTracker.cpp \
                           VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/RazerHydra.cpp \
                           VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/RazerHydraDevice.cpp \
                           VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/OculusRift.cpp

VRDEVICES_SOURCES = $(filter-out $(VRDEVICES_IGNORE_SOURCES),$(wildcard VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/*.cpp))
ifneq ($(VRDEVICES_USE_INPUT_ABSTRACTION),0)
  VRDEVICES_SOURCES += VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/Joystick.cpp
endif
ifneq ($(VRDEVICES_USE_BLUETOOTH),0)
  VRDEVICES_SOURCES += VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/WiimoteTracker.cpp
endif
ifneq ($(SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBUSB1),0)
  VRDEVICES_SOURCES += VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/RazerHydraDevice.cpp \
                       VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/OculusRift.cpp
endif

VRDEVICESDIREXT = VRDevices
VRDEVICESDIR = $(LIBDESTDIR)/$(VRDEVICESDIREXT)
VRDEVICES = $(VRDEVICES_SOURCES:VRDeviceDaemon/VRDevices/%.cpp=$(VRDEVICESDIR)/lib%.$(PLUGINFILEEXT))
PLUGINS += $(VRDEVICES)

#
# The VR tracker calibrator plug-ins:
#

VRCALIBRATORS_SOURCES = $(wildcard VRDeviceDaemon/VRCalibrators/*.cpp)

VRCALIBRATORSDIREXT = VRCalibrators
VRCALIBRATORSDIR = $(LIBDESTDIR)/$(VRCALIBRATORSDIREXT)
VRCALIBRATORS = $(VRCALIBRATORS_SOURCES:VRDeviceDaemon/VRCalibrators/%.cpp=$(VRCALIBRATORSDIR)/lib%.$(PLUGINFILEEXT))
PLUGINS += $(VRCALIBRATORS)

#
# The Vrui device driver test program:
#

EXECUTABLES += $(EXEDIR)/DeviceTest

#
# The Vrui eye calibration program:
#

EXECUTABLES += $(EXEDIR)/EyeCalibrator

#
# The input device data file dumping program:
#

EXECUTABLES += $(EXEDIR)/PrintInputDeviceDataFile

#
# The Vrui calibration utilities:
#

EXECUTABLES += $(EXEDIR)/XBackground \
               $(EXEDIR)/MeasureEnvironment \
               $(EXEDIR)/ScreenCalibrator \
               $(EXEDIR)/AlignTrackingMarkers
ifneq ($(SYSTEM_HAVE_LIBUSB1),0)
  EXECUTABLES += $(EXEDIR)/OculusCalibrator
endif

# Set the name of the makefile fragment:
ifdef DEBUG
  MAKEFILEFRAGMENT = Share/Vrui.debug.makeinclude
else
  MAKEFILEFRAGMENT = Share/Vrui.makeinclude
endif

# Set the name of the make configuration file:
MAKECONFIGFILE = BuildRoot/Configuration.Vrui

# Set the name of the pkg-config meta data file:
PKGCONFIGFILE = Share/Vrui.pc

# Remember the names of all generated files for "make clean":
ALL = $(LIBRARIES) $(EXECUTABLES) $(PLUGINS) $(MAKEFILEFRAGMENT) $(MAKECONFIGFILE) $(PKGCONFIGFILE)

.PHONY: all
all: config $(ALL)

# Build all libraries before any plug-ins or executables:
$(PLUGINS): | $(LIBRARIES)
$(EXECUTABLES): | $(LIBRARIES)

########################################################################
# Pseudo-target to print configuration options and configure libraries
########################################################################

.PHONY: config
config: Configure-End

.PHONY: Configure-Begin
Configure-Begin:
    @echo "---- Vrui configuration options: ----"
ifneq ($(USE_RPATH),0)
    @echo "Run-time library search paths enabled"
else
    @echo "Run-time library search paths disabled"
endif

.PHONY: Configure-Install
Configure-Install: Configure-Threads \
                   Configure-USB \
                   Configure-Realtime \
                   Configure-GLSupport \
                   Configure-Images \
                   Configure-Sound \
                   Configure-ALSupport \
                   Configure-Video \
                   Configure-Vrui \
                   Configure-VRDeviceDaemon
    @echo "---- Vrui installation configuration ----"
ifdef SYSTEMINSTALL
    @echo "System-level installation requested"
endif
    @echo "Root installation directory               : $(INSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Header installation root directory        : $(HEADERINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Library installation root directory       : $(LIBINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Executable installation directory         : $(EXECUTABLEINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Plug-in installation root directory       : $(PLUGININSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Configuration file installation directory : $(ETCINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Shared file installation root directory   : $(SHAREINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Makefile fragment installation directory  : $(SHAREINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Build system installation directory       : $(MAKEINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "pkg-config metafile installation directory: $(PKGCONFIGINSTALLDIR)"
    @echo "Documentation installation directory      : $(DOCINSTALLDIR)"

.PHONY: Configure-End
Configure-End: Configure-Install
    @echo "---- End of Vrui configuration options ----"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the usual `-lusb-1.0`, you have to specify `-L directory/where/libusb/binary/is/located`.

Paths specified with `-L` will be searched before default paths while linking, so the linker will pick up the libusb-1.0 version compiled from source instead of the system one.

Comment: Thanks Stefano, but I forgot to include some additional details that I think may complicate things.

Comment: Hey Stefano, just wanted to let you and the community know, I did a little more digging into the build system, and found where I can set my own default path and do what you suggested and it worked. Thanks again